# How to deploy my ReactJS web application to Production Server

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx, deployment, ubuntu-18.04

My project is created with [ReactJS + php + mysql]. I already setup my local environments like `npm install` , `npm start` that's fine my website is running well in my local PC localhost:1234. After that I wanted to Deploy my ReactJS web app to production and for that I have a Digitalocean's Ubuntu 18.04 server . Therefor I installed Nginx web server and lets encrypted SSl I have a DNS xplosa.com that's all done which is pointing nginx homepage currently .

I have tried `npm build` that's too done without errors I can see a Directory called **dist** in my project it has my deployment source are unorganized bunch of files , anyways I just copy my dist contains(in my local pc) to my Nginx pointing directory (my digitalocean's ubuntu server) using SFTP method to transfered but after I restart my nginx and check my website on internet using www.xplosa.com  it has only showing my websites welcome message . after that I removed my source from that and kept it's welcome page it self , back to my local pc and checked it works in my local machine . Please help me to Deploy my ReactJS web app on production

Answer (score 0):

you can do it either using update ip table and redirecting you traffic from 80 port to your 1234 port in the production server.

you can use pm2 command to register the port to always running in the production server and then using ip table you can redirect the port.

Another option is just give the path of your build folder and in your config file (apache2 or nginx) to server.

Answer (score 0):

- First deploy and build your react app on the production.
- And configure Nginx to server the app as static:

```js
server {
  listen   80;
  server_name www.xplosa.com xplosa.com;

  rewrite ^(/.*)\.html(\?.*)?$ $1$2 permanent;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;

  root /home/ubuntu/www/your-path/;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri/  /home/ubuntu/www/your-path/index.html /home/ubuntu/www/your-path/$uri.html  $uri =404;

}
```

> Note :
>    the above configuration will serve the index page if the requested resources no exists,so it will serve your purpose well.
>   and you have to take care of the Php end with Nginx

Comment: Should I install npm , php on my production server to perform my website on live @Eslam Abu Hugair

Comment: yes `npm` must be installed in order to build the app

Comment: I need to serve my php files too , how can I do that

Comment: you can use apache instead of Nginx to server PHP and your react app static files, or you can combine the two (apache to serve the PHP) and Nginx as a load balancer